# What happenening with this theme setup?

Tags: magento

I am trying to put up this theme 'abc' but magento is not rendering it. Instead it is redirecting me to page not found. It's in the enterprise package and this theme is working fine on my other copy of installations both enterprise and community.

I have also tried by going into CMS home page and changing it's design using 'abc' theme and layout, but still getting this msg page not found on frontend. I am having cache disabled. Developer mode on and the is no error recorded in log files.

please suggest something.

[image]

[image]

[image]

edit---
If I go to page.xml in abc and comment the default layout. I get a black white page in frontend. So magento is actually finding it or if I break some xml tag and can see the error.

Comment: can please also try creating new design theme at: System -> Design?

Comment: Do not do that. It is not the place to set themes.

Comment: What happens when you go to site.com/home ? What are your settings under System > Web > Default Pages, and are the referenced pages available for the store you are trying to view ( CMS > Pages > Manage Content)

Comment: when I go to site.com/home I get the same page not found. I am having only one store so it is the default store. I don't have any option in CMS Pages to choose any other stores. If I go to Design and change the theme to default or change the package to base after that If I go to site.com/home again . I can see the home page.